# Set the credentials for HQGIS plugin

Tags: qgis-3, here-maps

I am trying to use HERE application for isochrones calculation. Few months ago everything works fine. I got my APP ID and API key for REST requests and used it in plugin menu. But now something is going wrong. I'm getting Python error:

```
File "C:/Users/Александр/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Hqgis\hqgis.py", line 951, in getIsochronesSingle
  ranges = [int(x) for x in intervalArray]
  File "C:/Users/Александр/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Hqgis\hqgis.py", line 951, in 
    ranges = [int(x) for x in intervalArray]
   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

How can I cope with this error?
I use QGIS 3.4, Win 7-64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin should still work. The above error is raised as you might not be following the input scheme for isochrone intervals. The error is not related to the APP CODE or  APP ID.

Intervals should look like:

```
400,800,1200
```

No blanks or any other characters. Please check again and raise an issue on the [github page](https://digital-geography.com/show-your-photos-in-qgis-and-arcgis-a-small-example/) of the plugin itself.

Please be aware, that HERE changed and restructured its API and the plugin is developed to work with the new API ([branch apikey](https://github.com/riccardoklinger/Hqgis/tree/apikey)). You need to work  with an apikey (get this from HERE as you did withn APP CODE and APP ID) instead of APP CODE and APP ID.